# PFQueryTableViewController not loading from Parse

Tags: ios, uitableview, parse-platform

I'm working with PFQueryTableViewController on TableViewController. The problem is: The data loads when I pull to refresh but they not load when the view loads.

I realize that all codes that have "self.tableView" are not working too like (self.tableView.reloadData) for example.

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit

class TableViewController: PFQueryTableViewController {
    var titulo = String()
    var sub_titulo = String()
    var url = String()
    var tipo = Int()

    @IBOutlet weak var imagemNerdmonster: UIImageView!

    override init(style: UITableViewStyle, className: String!) {
        super.init(style: style, className: className)
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath, object: PFObject?) -> PFTableViewCell {
        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as! PFTableViewCell!

        if cell == nil {
            cell = PFTableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")
        }

        // Extract values from the PFObject to display in the table cell
        if let titulo = object?["titulo"] as? String {
            cell?.textLabel?.text = titulo
        }
        if let sub_titulo = object?["sub_titulo"] as? String {
            cell?.detailTextLabel?.text = sub_titulo
        }
        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        let object = objectAtIndexPath(indexPath)
        self.titulo = object!.objectForKey("titulo") as! String
        self.sub_titulo = object!.objectForKey("sub_titulo") as! String
        self.url = object!.objectForKey("url") as! String
        self.tipo = object!.objectForKey("tipo") as! Int
        //Chama a segue
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("detailSegue", sender: self)
    }

    //In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        let svc = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailViewController
        svc.titulo = self.titulo
        svc.sub_titulo = self.sub_titulo
        svc.url = self.url
        svc.tipo = self.tipo
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        // Refresh the table to ensure any data changes are displayed
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
         self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100
         self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
         self.tableView.reloadData()
    }

    @IBAction func saveButton(sender: AnyObject) {
        //Return to table view
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }

    override func queryForTable() -> PFQuery {
        let query = PFQuery(className: "Conteudo")
        query.orderByAscending("createdAt")
        query.limit = 20
        //query.whereKey("currencyCode", equalTo:"EUR")
        return query
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
        //Configure the PFQueryTableView
        self.parseClassName = "Conteudo"
        self.textKey = "Titulo"
        self.pullToRefreshEnabled = true
        self.paginationEnabled = true
        self.objectsPerPage = 20
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this method to your class:

```
   override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    loadObjects()
}
```